# как очистить чат в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot

пишу бота с помощью библиотеки aiogram на пайтоне
как можно полностью очистить чат в тг боте?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Чат где? Личный? В канале?